# Validation and training curve remains flat

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm building a Tensorflow/Keras multiclassification model to identify 33 different species of birds. I've around 33,000 images and I've cleaned and removed the corrupt images and reduced the size of the images down from ~4347x3260 to 512x512 while retaining the aspect ratio.

I'm using a batch size of 32, input image size: 250x250. I've split the training/validation/test datasets into ratios of 80:10:10 which consists of 26253 training images, 3266 validation images and 3311 test images.

I've set the seed for the training image generator but the problem I've ran into is that when I change the number of layers/architecture the model stops improving at roughly the same level, around the 50% accuracy level and the validation/training curve remains flat albeit a gap starts to open up as seen in the figures below, a sign of overfitting but it retains the gap more or less.

[image: validation training accuracy]
**Updated Validation/Training Accuracy**
[image: Updated Validation/training Accuracy]

[image: Validation/training loss]
**Updated Validation/Training Loss**
[image: Updated Validation/training loss]

So, I plotted the graph of the optimized learning rate curve shown below and it is flat. I chose 1e-4 as my base learning rate and 1e-2 as my max learning rate and implemented a CLR as shown by [Smith](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01186.pdf). You can see the results below. Now it does improve the validation accuracy to around 58% at present and it hasn't started to really overfit yet, in fact all the curves are only slightly overfitting besides the original baseline graph. Maybe if I reduce the learning rate interval, the plot would give a better view of the curve.

[image: Loss v learning rate]

But would it be worth to train it for longer or can someone advise on the next steps to take? Any advice is welcome.
I've added updates to the graphs.

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2000    
IMG_HEIGHT = 250
IMG_WIDTH = 250
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = count_data_items(os.path.join(data_dir, 'train')) // batch_size

training_dir = 'train_test_val/train'

# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=45,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    fill_mode="reflect"
)
print("The number of training images: ")
train_datagen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  directory = training_dir,
  shuffle=True,
  target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  seed=123,
  class_mode='categorical'
)

test_dir = 'train_test_val/test'
print("The number of test images: ")
# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = test_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    #seed=123,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

val_dir = 'train_test_val/val'
print("The number of validation images: ")
# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = val_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    #seed=123,
  class_mode='categorical'
)

clr_step_size = int(4 * STEPS_PER_EPOCH)  
base_lr = 1e-4    
max_lr = 1e-2     
mode='triangular'
# The mode is set to triangular: that's equal to linear moce. 

def get_callbacks():
    return [
        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=run_logdir, histogram_freq=0, embeddings_freq=0, update_freq='epoch'),
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=21, verbose=1),
        #tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=8,verbose=1),
        tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, monitor ='val_loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=1),
        CyclicLR(base_lr=base_lr, max_lr=max_lr, step_size=clr_step_size, mode=mode)
        #tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(filename=csv_logger, separator=',', append=True)
    ]

def fit_model(model, n_epochs, initial_epoch=0, batch_size=batch_size):
    print("Fitting model on training data")
    history = model.fit(
        train_datagen,
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
        epochs=n_epochs,
        validation_data=val_datagen,
        validation_steps=n_val // batch_size,
        callbacks=get_callbacks(),
        verbose=1,
        initial_epoch = initial_epoch
    )



model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Edit: 20/03/2021** Applied InceptionV3 Transfer Learning Model and the Accuracy stalls out at 50%.

Comment: No no, please add them directly with proper formatting to the post, no screenshots.

Comment: Hi, I've added the code now.

Comment: Try to use fine tuning or transfer learning, it's going to be much better than training from scratch, If you are doing some type of academic research just ignore what I am saying.

Comment: Thanks 4.Pi.n, I'm doing in house research and was trying to see how far I can get without resorting to transfer learning.

Comment: Use [Keras tuner](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner) to tune the hyper parameters to improve the model performance. Thanks!

Comment: I've applied transfer learning using the InceptionV3 model and it also stalls out at 50% accuracy, so that has me thinking has it got to do with with the loss function.